# How to generate random values based on mean, standard deviation, skew and kurtosis in Python?

Tags: distributions, python, dataset, synthetic-data

Given these values, is it possible to generate random values that conform to this distribution (using Python<del>, but preferably without the SciPy package</del>)?

| Statistic | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Mean | 1.518 |
| Std Dev | 24.827 |
| Skew | 140.770 |
| Kurtosis | 25342.612 |
| Mode | 1 |
| Min | 1 |
| Max | 5735 |
| Count | 182557 |

Purpose: I'm trying to generate dummy / fake / synthetic data based on production data.

<del>I've tried finding several solutions, but most of them seem to use SciPy.</del>

<del>Reason for avoiding SciPy: I don't want to include ~200 MB of dependency just to use a single function.</del>

**EDIT**

Old title: *How to generate random values based on mean, standard deviation, skew and kurtosis in Python **without SciPy**?*

I gave up avoiding installation of yet another package. I've included SciPy in our dependencies, but I'm still stuck with finding a good solution for this.

The solutions I've tried either generate too many zeros or all ones. It's confusing to me because I don't have a statistical background, and I know that it's against SE's rules to simply ask for working code as solution, I'm asking for some tips or nudges in the right direction.

I've tried a few functions (`skewnorm`, `pearson3`, etc.) without understanding what they're doing and merely checking if the output looks as I expect. Of course, I couldn't find a satisfactory solution.

Comment: What function out of SciPy were you planning to use? What you describe here is a very skewed distribution. Can you give more details? Maybe you can cannibalise the package? Also remember that we can always remove `README`/documentation files without impeding our software's functionality. Finally, do you build from source or use a precompiled wheel, the latter is often bigger.

Comment: @usεr11852 (1) Not sure. I'm not from a statistical background. (2) More details: a column I'm trying to simulate data for has values from 1-5735. 1 has relatively higher chances of appearing (~98-99%), hence the skewness. I want to create a set of dummy values that also form this type of distribution; it doesn't have to generate the same statistics, approximate is enough.

Comment: Those moments alone do not determine the distribution.  However, there is a well-established family of distributions that was designed specifically to provide one distribution for most mathematically allowed combinations of those moments: the [Pearson system](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9610).

Comment: (+1) to what @whuber said, having those four moments do not uniquely define a distribution. We need more information to help you. Theoretically, we can estimate the [eCDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) and save the values in a file, then have that file as part of the binary and sample using that ecdf using only `numpy` functions.